# Is there a performance lost when overlinking and underlinking .so files?

Tags: linux, linker, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking

Some people are linking shared object files so that they have no entries in their NEEDED list, and when linking those SO files to a binary, put the transitive dependencies of all SO files into the NEEDED list of the created binary instead, disregarding of whether the binary actually needs those SO files.

The former act of not linking required SO files to a certain SO file is called *underlinking* and the latter act of linking too much SO files to a certain binary is called *overlinking*.

I am in a discussion with my coworker whether this scheme of building an application and its SO files imposes any performance cost either when building or running an application or its SO files. For example, perhaps there is an additional cost in dynamic symbol resolution for the PLT? Can someone shed some light on this please?

Comment: I would imagine the number of symbol resolutions & relocations matters more than the number of linked `.so` files. The dynamic linker certainly does like `dlopen`, maintaining a refcount of each `.so`

Answer (score 2):

It will certainly change the performance of symbol lookup, probably for the worse.  ELF symbol resolution is a breadth-first search starting from the symbol table of the executable itself, then the symbol tables of the DT_NEEDED libraries of the executable, then those libraries' DT_NEEDEDs' symbol tables, etc.  By overlinking the main executable you will probably force more symbol lookups to iterate through more libraries' symbol tables.